# Is there a way to make a Xamarin Forms application come up with a Rate this app dialog box?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've seen some applications where there's a button / link that when clicked opens up a dialog box with words similar to this:

```
       Enjoying xxx?

Tap a Star to rate it on the 
       App Store 

  star star star star star


         Not Now
```

I assume there's some way to do this on iOS as all these rating boxes look the same format.

Is there a way I can bring up a box like this in my Xamarin Forms application?

Comment: You can create your own view for the dialog box. Use the plugin RgPages for displaying  the dialog box. Plugin: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/StoreReviewPlugin

Comment: You can use `SKStoreReviewController.RequestReview();` method on ios 10 onwards.